# importing Python module using PYTHONPATH in ~/.bashrc not working

Tags: python, linux, python-module, pythonpath

I have been trying to do a simple import of a Python module and have been running into problems with this simple operation.

I have a directory structure as below:

```
/home/username/Desktop/project
  - src/
    - src_a.py
    - __init__.py
  - bin/
    - __init__.py
    - app.py
```

I added `/home/username/Desktop/project/src` to `PYTHONPATH` as given below:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/username/Desktop/project/src"
```

in my `~/.bashrc` followed by a `$ source ~/.bashrc`.

I am still not able to get the module to be recognized in `app.py` nor anywhere else. My editor also does not seem to recognize (autocomplete) the module. I search through multiple related questions and they point to the same procedure. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `bash` tag unless you can validate that the bash code really isn't doing what it should. If you run `env | grep PYTHONPATH`, is the value you expect shown? If it is, not a bash problem.

Comment: `env | grep PYTHONPATH` shows path, went ahead and removed `bash` tag....thank you :)

Comment: What exactly is the `import` line in app.py that isn't working?

Comment: `from src import testfunction`

Comment: `from src`? then you need `project` to be in your PYTHONPATH, not `project/src`, and `testfunction` needs to be defined in `src/__init__.py`.

Comment: thanks @CharlesDuffy. sorry, saw the comment late. Works now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created packages named `src` and `bin`. If you want to import something from a package, you need to set your `PYTHONPATH` to the directory containing the package's directory, in this case:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/username/Desktop/project
```

Now you should be able to import like this:

```
from src import src_a
```

Also, since `bin` is a package in the same directory you can import objects from it:

```
from bin import app
```

Comment: You are right....thanks! The module does seem to get imported and am able to import them successfully. But, my editor(s) still do not seem to autocomplete the functions. I tried with 2 different ones (Atom and Spyder) and both fail.

Comment: I finally got it to work with Atom! There was an additional setting where we could specify the particular package (`/home/username/Desktop/project`) that we would want and autocomplete works! Not sure why it does not automatically pick it up from `PYTHONPATH`. Thanks again, this answer solves my issue. :)